# Group by and then summarize with more than one element

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have a number of test results in a data frame `scores` as the following:

```
   name firstname score
1 McKay    Rodney     4
2 McKay    Rodney     2
3 McKay    Rodney     5
4  Weir Elizabeth     1
5  Weir Elizabeth     8
```

I want to compute the quantiles of the score distribution for each of the people. If I just wanted one fixed quantile (say the median), I can do the following:

```
quantile_df <- score_df %>%
    group_by(name, firstname) %>%
    summarize(q50 = median(score))
```

The resulting data frame will have the columns `name`, `firstname` and `q50`. This does not scale if I want to compute an arbitrary number of quantiles. Say I want three of them (for now), so the result would be the following (numbers are nonsense):

```
   name firstname    q quantiles
1 McKay    Rodney 0.25         1
2 McKay    Rodney 0.50         3
3 McKay    Rodney 0.75         7
4  Weir Elizabeth 0.25         2
5  Weir Elizabeth 0.50         4
6  Weir Elizabeth 0.75         6
```

It feels like `dplyr` should be the right package to find something for this, but I have not. Instead I would implement the following:

- Reduce the original data frame to the columns that I would group by.
- Take only the unique rows of that data frame.
- Use `mapply` on a function with the rows of this data frame containing `name` and `firstname`. This function will then filter `scores` such that name and first name match and extract the scores. The function returns a data frame with `name`, `firstname`, `q` and `quantiles`.
- There might be additional rows, then I would do a join with the result of the function and the reduced `scores` data frame to get those columns in (if any).

Does such a function exist in a common R library?

Comment: @Sotos: Absolutely, that's perfect! If you turn this into an answer I will happily accept it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the values into a list and use the `unnest()` method to expand, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(name, firstname) %>% 
 summarise(new = list(quantile(score))) %>% 
 unnest()
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 3
> # Groups:   name [2]
>    name  firstname   new
>    <fct> <fct>     <dbl>
>  1 McKay Rodney     2.00
>  2 McKay Rodney     3.00
>  3 McKay Rodney     4.00
>  4 McKay Rodney     4.50
>  5 McKay Rodney     5.00
>  6 Weir  Elizabeth  1.00
>  7 Weir  Elizabeth  2.75
>  8 Weir  Elizabeth  4.50
>  9 Weir  Elizabeth  6.25
> 10 Weir  Elizabeth  8.00
> ```

Comment: I suggest to use `enframe` to keep the names and reformat as a `tibble` that will unnest nicely: `df %>% group_by(name, firstname) %>% summarise(new = list(enframe(quantile(score),"q"))) %>% unnest`

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` answer:

```
score_df <- data.frame(name = sample(c('Bob', 'Sue', 'Lorna'), 100, T)
                       , score = sample(1:100))

library(data.table)
setDT(score_df)


score_df[, quantile(score), name]
#      name     V1
#  1:   Bob   1.00
#  2:   Bob  20.00
#  3:   Bob  41.00
#  4:   Bob  82.00
#  5:   Bob  99.00
#  6: Lorna   2.00
#  7: Lorna  23.00
#  8: Lorna  52.00
#  9: Lorna  77.00
# 10: Lorna 100.00
# 11:   Sue   7.00
# 12:   Sue  33.75
# 13:   Sue  50.00
# 14:   Sue  64.50
# 15:   Sue  94.00
```

Or, if you want to include the percentages

```
score_df[, {qu <- quantile(score)
            .(q = names(qu), quantiles = qu)}
         , name]

#      name    q quantiles
#  1:   Bob   0%      1.00
#  2:   Bob  25%     20.00
#  3:   Bob  50%     41.00
#  4:   Bob  75%     82.00
#  5:   Bob 100%     99.00
#  6: Lorna   0%      2.00
#  7: Lorna  25%     23.00
#  8: Lorna  50%     52.00
#  9: Lorna  75%     77.00
# 10: Lorna 100%    100.00
# 11:   Sue   0%      7.00
# 12:   Sue  25%     33.75
# 13:   Sue  50%     50.00
# 14:   Sue  75%     64.50
# 15:   Sue 100%     94.00
```

To group by 2 columns in `data.table` you can do e.g.

```
score_df[, quantile(score), .(name, firstname)]
```

If you happen to have `tibble` or `tidyverse` loaded as well, you can do

```
library(tidyverse)
score_df[, enframe(quantile(score), 'q')
         , name]

#      name    q value
#  1: Lorna   0%   9.0
#  2: Lorna  25%  35.0
#  3: Lorna  50%  65.5
#  4: Lorna  75%  85.0
#  5: Lorna 100%  97.0
#  6:   Bob   0%   7.0
#  7:   Bob  25%  24.5
#  8:   Bob  50%  48.0
#  9:   Bob  75%  65.5
# 10:   Bob 100% 100.0
# 11:   Sue   0%   1.0
# 12:   Sue  25%  19.0
# 13:   Sue  50%  40.0
# 14:   Sue  75%  67.0
# 15:   Sue 100%  98.0
```